# Question on series $\frac {\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, special-functions, alternative-proof, fake-proofs

Prove that:
$$\frac {2\Gamma'(2z)}{\Gamma(2z)}-\frac {\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}-\frac {\Gamma \prime(z+\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(z+\frac{1}{2})} =2 \log 2$$

But I obtain this equal zero:
$$\frac {2\Gamma'(2z)}{\Gamma(2z)} - \frac {\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)} - \frac {\Gamma'(z+\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(z+\frac{1}{2})} = 0$$

What's the correct answer? $0$    or   $2\log 2$?
Can anyone help?

Comment: The correct answer is $2\log(2)$

Comment: This is the [duplication formula for the digamma function](http://www.johndcook.com/gamma_identities.html#polygamma_multiplication).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$\Gamma(z)\cdot \Gamma(z+1/2)=2\sqrt{\pi}\cdot 4^z\cdot \Gamma(2z) $$
by considering the logarithmic derivative of both sides we get:
$$\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}(z)+\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}(z+1/2)=2\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}(2z)+2\log 2.$$

Comment: The first formula is the [duplication formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) for $\Gamma$.